# New to Android. How to launch Score screen through Intent after Main game is lost

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to launch a score screen a few seconds after my android game is lost. But Android studio doesn't recognize startActivity and the new Intent constructor isn't liking my parameters. Any guidance?

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                Intent startGame = new Intent(MissionView.this, ScoreScreen.class);
                startGame.setAction(startGame.ACTION_SEND);
                startActivity(startGame);
```

*** UPDATE
[startActivity method not accepting the intent I just created with getContext()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4mfP.png)
                }
    }, 2000); //ScoreScreen launched after 2 seconds

Comment: It looks like you're doing this in a `View` subclass, which is why that method and that constructor can't be resolved. You should be doing this in the `Activity` containing your `View`, instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Is this why it's not recognizing the method startActivity(startGame)? Is there a workaround I can still launch an activity within the View class?

Comment: "Is this why it's not recognizing the method startActivity(startGame)?" - Yep. "Is there a workaround I can still launch an activity within the View class" - Yeah, you could call `startActivity()` on the `View`'s `getContext()` return, but I would have to say that it's not good practice.

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah, I really want to stick as much to best practice as possible, but I'm afraid I'm in a bit of a time crunch. Hopefully I can go back and improve it later. I tried changing it to context before, but then startActivity isn't taking the intent I made as a parameter. I've updated the question above with the error I'm getting now.

Comment: Your passing MissionView.this as the first constructor of your intent. As others have hinted at, the first parameter should be the currently running activity.